# Умножение с помощью рекурсии используя только ++ и -- операторы

Tags: c#, c++, алгоритм, рекурсия

Помогите пожалуйста создать программу, который будет умножить 2 целые число, используя рекурсию. При этом использовать только циклы, ++ и -- операторы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
unsigned int sum(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    return !a ? b : !b ? a : sum(--a,++b);
}

unsigned int prod(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    return !a ? 0 : !b ? 0 : sum(b,prod(--a,b));
}
```

Устроит? :)

Или вот, [с использованием лямбд](https://ideone.com/6oxHNZ):

```
auto prod = [](unsigned int a, unsigned int b) -> unsigned int
{
    auto sum = [](unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
    {
        auto impls = [](unsigned int a, unsigned int b, auto conts) -> unsigned int
        {
            return !a ? b : !b ? a : conts(--a,++b,conts);
        };
        return impls(a,b,impls);
    };
    auto contp = [sum](unsigned int a, unsigned int b, auto contp) -> unsigned int
    {
        return !a ? 0 : !b ? 0 : sum(b,contp(--a,b,contp));
    };
    return contp(a,b,contp);
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << prod(7,8) << endl;
    cout << prod(700,800) << endl;

}
```

Comment: это помощь? *(1 символ нужен...)*

Comment: @Igor А что же это? Рекурсивное решение. Что вам не нравится?

Comment: загибание пальцев за Вовку в тридевятом царстве

Comment: Вы написали b+prod...  но надо только ++ и --,   + нельза

Comment: @ArtyomArshakyan Сейчас исправим :)

Comment: "... пять церквей и колоколен, да еще и недоволен!"

Comment: @Harry чего так сложно?)

Comment: @pavel Чтоб вас не обогнать :)

Comment: @Igor Такие задачки - в развлечение. Добавьте метку "соревнование", и пойдет на ура :)

Comment: @Harry оцените мою идею на шаблонах.

Comment: @pavel А мою - с лямбдами :) Так и вспомнился анекдот, когда генерал - дембелю: "Да ты знаешь, кто я такой?!!! Да я командир дивизии!!!" - на что дембель отвечает "Ну что, тоже неплохо..." :)

Comment: @Harry мне понравился ваше решение, с использованием 2 функции. Но при тестирование, нашел, что когда a<0 программа выдает ошибку.

Comment: @ArtyomArshakyan Естественно - стек-то ограничен... А у меня все типы - `unsigned`. Похоже, вы не задумались, что это значит.

Comment: @Harry да, я не люблю с++,  по этому перевел ваш код в с#.  и столкнулся с этой проблемой. самое интересное, что когда b<0 все нормально,  но когда а<0, выдает ошибку.  Ладно, спс,  попробую сам исправить

Comment: @ArtyomArshakyan: вот вариант add() и mul() функций с хвостовой рекурсией, которую компилятор автоматом в инструкции сложения, умножения преобразует: https://godbolt.org/g/T4zVds

Answer (score 4):

Как и просили, только ++ и --.

```
int S1(int x, int y){
    return y?S1(++x,--y):x;
}

int M(int x,int y){
    return y?S1(M(x,--y), x):0;
}


int main(void) {
    cout << M(50,8);
    return 0;
}
```

Вот в шаблонах:

```
constexpr int S(int a, int b){
    return b?S(++a,--b):a;
}

constexpr int D(int x){
   return --x;
}


template<int n, int m>
class M {
public:
    static const int res = S(M<D(n), m>::res, m);
};


template<int n>
class M<0,n>{
    public: 
    static const int res = 0;
};

int main() {
    cout << M<5,8>::res;
    return 0;
}
```