# Необходимо вычислить y=x^N. Задачу решить с применение рекурсии и без неё

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Задачу решить по следующему алгоритму: y=(x^(N/2))^2, если N чётное; и y=x*x^(N-1), если N нечетное.Задачу решить с применение рекурсии и без неё.

Не могу разобраться, как выполнить задачу 2-мя способами. Сам я выполнил, если не ошибаюсь, рекурсивно. Но как реализовать код без применения рекурсии - не понимаю.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double  y, x;
    int N;
    cout << "Input x \n"; cin >> x;
    cout << "Input N \n"; cin >> N;
     //not recursive
    if (N % 2 == 0) { //if i is even number, do function 1
            y = (pow(pow(x, N / 2), 2)); //function 1
            cout << "y =" << y << "\n";
    }
    else {
            y = x * pow(x, N - 1);//functio 2
            cout << "y =" << y << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да нет, рекурсии у вас нет...

Рекурсивное решение - вот:

```
double Pow(double x, unsigned int N)
{
    if (N == 0) return 1;
    else if (N%2 == 0)
    {
        double z = Pow(x,N/2);
        return z*z;
    }
    else
        return x*Pow(x,N-1);
}
```

Теперь итеративное сами сумеете на его основании написать? оно даже проще :) Вобщем, смотрите [тут](https://ideone.com/ADhN3s).

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/737184 веселее варианты)